# Change the image drawable to a text by button click

Tags: android

I wanted to change the image drawable to a text on button click. I have a symbol tick(which is a button). On clicking the image, it should show a text "abc". I have tried but my text is coming over the image. I want only the text on button click,the image should not be seen. Can anyone help

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            button.setText("abc");
                        }
                    });
```

My xml code is

```
 <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_a"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/box" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        button.setBackgroundResource(0);
                        button.setText("abc");
                    }
                });
```